# Service module contextual filter

Tags: views, services

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78374/how-send-argument-to-services-module-viewscontextual-filters/78451#78451)  from 2 years ago (to which I am not allowed to comment) to the question "[How send argument to Services Module (Views+Contextual filters)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78374)" contains something about passing contextual filter value to the service module. It is about this URL:

```
http://test.url/endpoint/path?uid=123
```

My question here: what exactly is that "path"?
Is that machine name of the view?

Comment: There was a question # 78374 i can't comment on it

Comment: Alright resolved the issue make sure when the view is created there is no other page or block apparently something setup in my MASTER page was causing it to not work.  i.e http://localhost/extra/api/views/service.json?tag=11584

Comment: OK friend Atif ... Have you noticed how "I" intercepted your question when it showed up in the vote-to-close review queue? I was like 5 secs close to "vote to close". But after reading it like 5 times (yes!) I noticed it was NOT what I first thought (= a comment to another question/answer somewhere). After transforming your question to a way-less-confusing question, I noticed there was even a comment to this question that ... contained the answer to your own question. So I took the liberty to massage that into a real answer. Now it's your turn: is it "the" answer you want to mark "accepted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your issue: make sure when the view is created there is no other page or block.

It seems something setup in your MASTER page was causing it to not work. i.e `localhost/extra/api/views/service.json?tag=11584`